# FusionTablesLayer Issue to show area

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to highlighted area by creating layer where user click on map.It do not create layer.

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: tableId,
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + '),1))',
            limit: 1
          }
        });
        layer.setMap(map);
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2ekv1j/6/) for complete code.

What is the issue with layer?

Comment: I get a javascript error in your fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`

Comment: I updated the fiddle,i extract this code from a working file to simplify thiings

Comment: Your [table only has data in minnesota](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col51+from+16TsGfelZ4TXk5i9ZJt5HpJTNSP2D4x5M1nx0a78&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=46.521464870509895&lng=-93.3612905&t=1&z=6&l=col51).

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can get data for Dubai/UAE?

Answer (score 0):

1. you have a javascript error in your fiddle
2. your table only contains data for Minnesota (so the fiddle will only work in Minnesota).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2ekv1j/7/)

working code snippet:

```js
var marker = null;
var layer = null;

function initialize() {
    var tableId = "16TsGfelZ4TXk5i9ZJt5HpJTNSP2D4x5M1nx0a78";
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.0813500, 55.1440750);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.0813500, 55.1440750)
    };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: tableId,
            }
        });
    
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "Minnesota"}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
        var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
        // Center of map
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                map: map
            });
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        }
        if (!layer || !layer.setQuery || !layer.getMap || (layer.getMap() == null)) { 
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: tableId,
                where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + '),1))',
                limit: 1
            },
            map: map
        });
        layer.setMap(map);
        } else {
            layer.setQuery({
                select: 'geometry',
                from: tableId,
                where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + '),1))',
                limit: 1
            });
        }

    }); //end addListener
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```